# ShareThis in header rather than content type?

Tags: 7, social-network

I am adding Drupal ShareThis to a header mini-panels, but the buttons are not displayed. Firebug tells me that the corresponding code is not there at all. How can I display ShareThis buttons outside of content types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

- Go to menu Structure>Blocks.
- find the ShareThis block.
- set the block region settings for the theme you are using
- go to block configuration and make sure the block is visible for all required pages, content types, roles, users
- go to menu Configuration>Web Services>ShareThis
- go to 'Advanced' section
- find 'Location' settings
- select 'Block' to select the ShareThis widget should appear as a block and not in a node content.

Comment: I tried all of this, but it did not solve the issue. The save configuration does not work in 2.3 (http://drupal.org/node/1507684). I think it has to do with a regression between ShareThis 2.2 and 2.3. I reinstalled 2.2 and it worked.