# sharethis block not appearing in panels

Tags: panels, social-network

I'm using [sharethis 7.x-2.4](https://www.drupal.org/node/1294176) with [panels 7.x-3.2](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels/releases/7.x-3.2)

Previously, when I was using [sharethis 7.x-2.2](https://www.drupal.org/node/1294176), there was no option to insert sharethis in panels. Since upgrading, it appears in the 'miscellaneous' category. But after inserting it into a pane, the sharethis buttons don't appear on my panel node pages.

I've tried setting the sharethis location to 'block' (as described in [ShareThis in header rather than content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27059/sharethis-in-header-rather-than-content-type)) 
and then re-entering it in the panel, but it still doesn't show.

Sharethis is displaying normally for content types that aren't using panels.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: This would probably be more at home in the issue queue for ShareThis.